# Why aren't javabean features built into the root JAVA object?

Tags: java, spring, class, object, javabeans

I'm having a hard time understanding why javabeans are necessary and why they didn't just place the javabean features directly into the object class(root class) in java?

My understanding is you turn an object(instance) into a java bean and that way you get all the benefits like serializable and so on for all the objects in the bean.  But if that is the case, why even have a separate bean class for this, why not just have built into the root object class?

Or am I not understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not understanding it correctly.
There is no actual Java class or interface that is a bean. It is merely a pattern, a convention.

The bean convention is basically that a class will publicly expose some or all of its properties via public getXxx and setXxx methods, where XXX is the name of the property.

Beans generally should be serializable,  but any class can be serializable, and does not need to follow the bean convention.

Comment: ok that clears stuff up.  So why put a set of objects into a bean vs accessing them directly?  Is it because some objects are linked to other objects therefore its best to encapsulate them and to make sure objects are consistent/manageable?

Comment: And why not just make a constructor for every situation needed vs creating a bean that sets those properties?

Comment: Setters are a bad idea! I want my fields to be final, so that the compiler ensures that they are initialized exactly once. Setters break immutability.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that answer by Grey: even if there would be a Bean interface or method - not every fruit is an apple!

Meaning: there are zillions of classes that are just fine NOT being beans.

Beyond that: serialization as java does it was often found to be not that helpful. There are good reasons why we mostly serialize into JSON nowadays. In other words: we are pretty happy now that not all classes implement Serializeable by default; because Object being a Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Just to talk about the no-argument constructor part of the bean pattern: A class does have a no argument constructor by default, but as soon as you create another constructor, that effectively removes it, as you probably know. But if you were forced to always have a no-argument constructor, this would be really annoying if you had a class which had a final field which is assigned by an argument in the constructor. You would then need to have some no argument constructor which either assigns everything to null, or throws an exception to tell other developers not to use the no argument so, which is just ugly.